# Authentication Issue with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jwt

I've encountered an intriguing issue. Despite configuring a Security Filter Chain to manage my requests and explicitly specifying that the path '/random' should not require authentication, I'm experiencing a peculiar behavior. When I make a request to this path, I receive a Status 200 response with no body. Strangely, if I include a Bearer Token, the resource is successfully provided. Any suggestions or insights on why this might be happening? Here's my code:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig {

    private final JwtAuthenticationFilter JwtAuthenticationFilter;
    private final UserService userService;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {


        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/random").permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider())
                .addFilterBefore(JwtAuthenticationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .httpBasic();

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {

        final DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userService);
        authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
        return authenticationProvider;

    }
}
```

and the controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/random")
public class Random {

    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<String> getRandom() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Random response");
    }
}
```

I would be grateful for any help and provide more code if needed!

Comment: To understand more you can enable debug by `@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)` and `logging.level.org.springframework.security=TRACE`. It will show why the API is failing when you are not sending the Bearer token